# Is it possible to use different OpenDNS settings for different users?

Tags: opendns

I've set up my home network to use OpenDNS, but it would be nice if I could apply different settings to different users, or different computers.

Is this possible? My router/DHCP server is a Linksys WRT54GL, using the Linksys firmware.

The reason I'm doing this it so have one set of restrictions for the kids, who have their own accounts and a different set of restrictions for the adults.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: One set of restrictions for the kids, who have their own accounts, a different set of restrictions for the adults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, OpenDNS settings are per-IP only.

Comment: I think you're right, as I don't see any way OpenDNS could recognise users, except for the (single) public IP address that is making the DNS requests.

Comment: +1 OpenDNS is per 'network' only.

Answer (score 3):

Netgear use a live parental controls software powered by OpenDNS — and this is possible. Check [this Netgear video](http://content.webcollage.net/apps/cs/mini-site/netgear/module/netgear/wcpc/parental-controls/tab/demo?channel-product-id=&enable-reporting=true&showtabs=). Not sure if OpenDNS can do alone.

Answer (score 1):

you could set up DNS per system, and it'll ignore the DNS server the router is using. You will ONLY be using the default DNS server if there isn't one explicitly set.

Comment: that's right, leave the router at the default DNS settings and configure each machine. +1

Comment: OpenDNS settings are per IP. So even if each machine is configured to use OpenDNS individually, they'll all have the same external IP and thus the same settings, no?